# Why does quote in quoted variable expansion works well in bash?

Tags: bash

I am learning quote in bash.
I got a code

```
unset unset_var
test_var="${unset_var:-"abc"}"
echo "test_var = $test_var"
tset_var = abc
```

My question comes from the line, "${unset_var:-"abc"}"

I interupted the line in two ways,

The first ways is

```
"${unset_var:-"abc"}" =
(quoted string: "${unset_var:-") +
(unquoted string: abc) +
(quoted string: "}")
```

The second way is

```
"${unset_var:-"abc"}" =
("${}") + (abc:-"abc")
```

The first way is intuitive for me.

The second way is similar to independent quote in sub-shell from parent-shell, like

```
"$(command "aug")"  # quote in sub-shell is independent from one in parent-shell
```

I could not find a instruction of this question in bash manual.

Someone who knows how it works, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any assignment statement of the form

```
name=value
```

`value` undergoes quote-removal, which is the removal of any quotes that are not a result of expansions applied to `value`.

With

```
test_var="${unset_var:-"abc"}"
```

the quotes around the parameter expansion are clearly not the result of any expansions, so they are removed. The question is, how are the inner quotes treated?

According to the man page,

> In [`${parameter:-word}`], `word` is subject to tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion."

However, since `"abc"` does not undergo any of the four named expansions, the surrounding quotes are not the product of an expansion, and so are removed per quote removal. Thus,

```
test_var="${unset_var:-"abc"}"
```

is equivalent to

```
test_var="${unset_var:-abc}"
```

which is equivalent to

```
test_var=abc
```

Comment: Thank you for beautiful explanation. Let me confirm one thing. test_var="${unset_var:-"abc"}" -> test_var="abc" And removal of quote at assignment you mentioned above is applied. As a result, test_var=abc . Is it correct? The form,  test_var="${unset_var:-"abc"}", is a little bit different from form, name=value. I am afraid I am asking to much trivial but I could not 100 percent sure whether the mechanism of the second quote removal is exactly same as one of the first removal. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe, at the assignment, expansion processes including quote removal are done to right hand side string. In case of test_var="${unset_var:-"abc"}", same expansion processes are applied to "abc" at its location. So test_var="${unset_var:-abc}" may be correct and test_var="abc" may be incorrect.